# Is there any way to use event parameters to trigger in-app messages in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-in-app-messaging

It seems that currently, in-app messages triggered by events only respond to the occurrence or not of the event. One of the richest event in an app is screen_view, which would only be helpful when using the values stored as parameters of the event.

Is there any workaround to do it?

---

**What I'd like to achieve is this:**

A user opens any screen in the app, triggering the screen_view event, with the firebase_screen_class parameter specified (this is triggered automatically by the iOS api as far as I'm concerned).

An In-App Message is triggered when that specific event is triggered with an specific value in a parameter.

---

**I explored two options:**

1. Firebase in-App Message is set to appear when an event with an specific parameter value occurs.
2. Event is captured using Firebase Cloud Functions, triggering the In-App message when the parameter condition is met directly from the function.

Unfortunately I haven't find anything in the documentation, nor in Google or Github that makes me thing this is possible yet.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same thing and reached out to Firebase support. Here's what they told me

> Currently, it is not possible to use a specific event (e.g
> screen_view) with a specified parameter (e.g firebase_screen) as an
> event trigger for Firebase In-App Messaging. As a workaround, to use
> the specific parameter for FIAM targeting, you may define it as an
> audience first to be able to target it on the composer.

I did not adopt their workaround, but I tried doing the below and it worked for me:

1. Create an extra Firebase event tag via GTM, set action as "Add Event", and define an event name for it e.g. "screen_a". This is triggered upon your desired combination of event_name and firebase_screen_class value
2. In Firebase Console, set the FIAM to be triggered by the event name you have defined in step 1 (i.e. screen_a)